# java simple bouncing ball flickers

Tags: java

This is just a simple red ball going up and down and i see it flickering. I already saw few subjects about that but did not find any answer that helped me. 
Thank you :)

The Window class with the go method that makes the ball goes up and down.
The panel that also contains the ball positions and that just repaints.

Window.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Window();
    }

    public Panel pan = new Panel();

    public Window() 
    {
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setContentPane(pan);
        this.setVisible(true);

        go();
    }

    private void go() 
    {
        int vecY = 1;
        while (true) 
        {
            if (pan.y <= 100)
            {
                vecY = 1;
            }
            else if (pan.y >= 400)
            {
                vecY = -1;
            }
            pan.y += vecY;
            pan.repaint();
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Panel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel 
{

  public int x = 300;
  public int y = 300;

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
  {
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
  }

}
```

Comment: Call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: thx for your answer :) i did now first line of paintComponent i added : super.paintComponent(g), it doesnt change anything it is still flickering

Comment: It’s possible you have a thread race condition, I’d recommend using a Swing Timer over your current while loop

Comment: and i just realized if i move my mouse in the created window it stops flickering otherwise it does like if i dont move it in the window or if i move it or not elsewhere on the screen

Comment: That's because the mouse is triggering additional repaints to the screen

Comment: oh okay, what do you mean by thread race condition ? (in my case)

Comment: The thread which is painting the UI is not the same thread you're updating the position from, this means that by the time the component is painted, it's possible that the y position has been updated a number of times, increasing the distance the object "appears" to have traveled, which can make it look like it's flickering

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible issues.  The primary issue is likely to be a thread race condition between your `while-loop` and the `paintComponent` method.

Your `while-loop` is capable of change the state of the `y` position before the `paintComponent` has a chance to paint it's state.  Painting is done at the leisure of the paint sub system, so calling `repaint` simply makes a request to the `RepaintManager` which decides what and when an actual paint cycle might take place, this means that you could be dropping frames.

For most animations in Swing, a Swing `Timer` is more the capable.  It's safe to update the UI from within, as the `ActionListener` is called within the context of the EDT but won't block the EDT

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Window();
            }
        });
    }

    public Panel pan = new Panel();

    public Window() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane(pan);
        pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

        go();
    }

    private void go() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pan.updateAnmationState();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public class Panel extends JPanel {

        private int x = 300;
        private int y = 300;

        private int vecY = 1;

        public void updateAnmationState() {
            if (y <= 100) {
                vecY = 1;
            } else if (y >= 400) {
                vecY = -1;
            }
            y += vecY;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        }

    }
}
```

This example worked fine for me on MiniMac

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. so even if i did not understand everything in your code, i just copied-pasted it and it does still flickers for me

Comment: well same than before it does not when i move the mouse but like you saying it does more repaint, anyway thank you for your time, what do you think could still be the pb ?

Comment: Your graphics card/driver. You can try reducing the `Timer` to 5 millseconds